# Replace does not work when replacing text inside a span element

Tags: javascript

I have a script that puts math questions (from a mySQL database) on a page. For instance

- Find 10% of 50
- Find 10% of 60
- Find 10% of 55

You get the idea.

I've written a script to avoid repeating the first word. It's overly long and complicated but I wrote it and I'm new to this and pretty proud that i did it.

Anyway, this script takes the first word and puts it in a variable called introtext.

I then am trying to take my questions and remove this introtext so it's not repeated

```
var q = q.replace(p1introtext,"");
```

This works really well when the value of introtext is something like 'simplify' 'find' or even a reasonably long sentence. However if the intro text contains html formatting like

```
<span class = "smaller">Find</span>
```

then the " are causing the program to ignore the replace function.

I do realize there is an element of bad database design here, but it's a big one and it will take ages to get rid of all the span tags, which are actually quite useful when using the questions in other formats.

I cannot just hide the .smaller class using css as it can also appear in bits of the question I want to display.

I'm really confused as to how I can work with this

Comment: `q = <span="someClass">aVariable</span>` isn't valid Javascript, are there meant to be quotes around it? i.e. `q = '<span="someClass">aVariable</span>'`

Comment: also `.replace(aVariable, "");` will replace whatever the **value of** the variable `aVariable` is with an empty string .. it doesn't replace the string `"aVariable"` ... e.g. if `aVariable = "fred"` then `.replace(aVariable, "");` is equivalent of `.replace("fred", "");`

Comment: Yeah! That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose your text in single quotes since you're using double quotes in your text.

```
q = '<span="someClass">aVariable</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var q = '<span="someClass">aVariable</span>';
q = q.replace("aVariable", "");
console.log(q);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try this one

```
var q = '<span="someClass">aVariable</span>';
q = q.replace("aVariable", "");
console.log(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var q = '<span="someClass">aVariable</span>';
q = q.replace('aVariable', "");
console.log(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use backticks with template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and aVariable is not a variable in your code, it's a string

```
var q = `<span="someClass">aVariable</span>`;
q = q.replace("aVariable", "a");
```

[Working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflowanswer)